# Toogle device toolbar

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, element, inspect

i got a problem when I press the "inspect" my signup form get so small. I thought there's something to do with my CSS so I tried deleting my CSS but it didn't change, it's still the same size "980x2122". so I tried deleting everything and left a single text but didn't change. I'm still learning so bear with me

[image]

Comment: Click on the small tab preceeding elements tab in the console.It will change the screen to desktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you set your toolbar devices too specific.. In this case, you specified for iPhone X only. because of it you can't change the size and stays at "980x2122" (iPhone display) even though you did refresh it. Try to change it into "Responsive" mode. It will Response to many kind of type size. Maybe this will help you

(Detail : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV59R.png])

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the Toogle Device Toolbar as marked in the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: yes but i mean how will i normalize the size of the form if i want it to view this way